# C++ %s too many arguments

Tags: c++

имею такой код

```
char USBpath[64];
void get_USB_SD_path(int device);
bool checkUSB(void);

void get_USB_SD_path(int device){
    uint i;
    char * temp1;
    if((device == 0) || (device == 2)) {
        FILE *p2 = popen("df | grep -v /mnt | grep sd | cut -d'%' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 2","r");
        memset(USBpath,'\0',64);
        fread(USBpath,sizeof(char),63,p2);
        pclose(p2);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(USBpath);i++) {
            if(USBpath[i]=='\n')
                USBpath[i]='\0';
        }
        if(strlen(USBpath)>5) {
            if((USBpath[0]=='/')&&(USBpath[1]=='m')&&(USBpath[2]=='e')&&(USBpath[3]=='d')&&(USBpath[4]=='i')&&(USBpath[5]=='a')&&(USBpath[6]=='/')) {
                temp1 = USBpath + 12;                               // remove "/media/"
            }
            else {
                temp1 = USBpath + 7;                                // remove "/media/"
            }
            sprintf(USBname,"%s",temp1);
        }
    }
    if((device == 1) || (device == 2)) {
        FILE *p4 = popen("df | grep -v /mnt | grep nvm | cut -d'%' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 2","r");
        memset(SDpath,'\0',64);
        fread(SDpath,sizeof(char),63,p4);
        pclose(p4);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(SDpath);i++) {
            if(SDpath[i]=='\n')
                SDpath[i]='\0';
        }
        if(strlen(SDpath)>5) {
            if((SDpath[0]=='/')&&(SDpath[1]=='m')&&(SDpath[2]=='e')&&(SDpath[3]=='d')&&(SDpath[4]=='i')&&(SDpath[5]=='a')&&(SDpath[6]=='/')) {
                temp1 = SDpath + 12;                                // remove "/media/"
            }
            else {
                temp1 = SDpath + 7;                                 // remove "/media/"
            }
            sprintf(SDname,"%s",temp1);
        }
    }
}

bool checkUSB(void) {
    int result=0;
    struct statfs usb;
    result = statfs(USBpath, &usb);
    if((USBpath == NULL) || result) {
        USB_mounted = false;
        //printf("140: no USB device USB path '%s' statfs = %d \n", USBpath, result);
        std::cout << "140: no USB device USB path '%s' statfs = %d" <<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        switch(usb.f_type){
            case 0xEF53:                                                //ext2, ext3
                USBfileSystem = 1;
                break;
            case 0x4d44:                                                //fat
                USBfileSystem = 2;
                break;
            default:                                                    // unknown
                USBfileSystem = 0;
                break;
        }
        USB_mounted = true;
    }

    USBblockSizeKB = usb.f_bsize / 1024;
    USBfreeSpaceMB = (usb.f_bavail * USBblockSizeKB) / 1024;
    USBtotalSizeMB = (usb.f_blocks * USBblockSizeKB) / 1024;
    if(USBfreeSpaceMB < 0) return false;
    return true;
}

void test(){
    FILE *p;
    char result[255];
    int i=0;
    p = popen("rsync --info=progress2 %s/testfile100M %s/testfile100Mss\n", "r", USBpath, USBpath); //copy the same file to the same drive

    if(!p) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening pipe.\n");
        std::cout << ("Error opening pipe.\n") << std::endl;
    }

    while(fgets(result, 255, p)){
    // std::cout << (result) << std::endl;
    }

    char name[100];
    char name3[100];
    char *name2;
    char wert[100];
    char trennzeichen[] = "100\%";

    name2 = strtok(result, trennzeichen);
    sprintf(name, "%s", name2);
    name2 = strtok(NULL, trennzeichen);
    sprintf(name3, "%s", name2);
    name2 = strtok(NULL, trennzeichen);
    sprintf(wert, "%s", name2);

 /*
    for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
        wert[i]=wert[i+2];
        if(wert[i-1] == 'c') {
            wert[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
*/
   // std::cout << (name) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (name3) << std::endl;
  //  std::cout << (wert) << std::endl;
}
```

выдает на строчке `p = popen("rsync --info=progress2 %s/testfile100M %s/testfile100Mss\n", "r", USBpath, USBpath);` ошибку, что задано слишком много аргументов, хотя это не так.

Comment: Какой мрак. Тут от C++ только `cout`, а Qt я тут вообще не вижу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А как она описана в заголовочном файле? Думаю, что с двумя аргументами.

[Отсюда](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);
int pclose(FILE *stream);
```

С чего вы решили, что `popen` - функция с переменным количеством аргументов, да еще и в стиле `printf` - с такими же спецификаторами формата?